# MS Access creation Python issue

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, ms-access

Trying to create a database using Python 2.7 and pypyodbc.

I have a user input for a name and I added the '.mdb' extension then I try to create the database and it throws a type exception error.

How is my syntax wrong?

```
    projectName = self.textBrowser.text() + '.mdb'
    pypyodbc.win_create_mdb(projectName)

    conn = pypyodbc.win_connect_mdb(projectName)
```

Comment: We would need more information. What is projectName right after the first line? Is the path valid?

Comment: My understanding is it defaults to current directory which is what I want. So....example projectName = 'databaseName.mdb'  If I just hard-code it in it goes to the working directory.

Comment: You are correct that it should go to the working directory, but self.textBrowser.text() could be passing in a path that doesn't exist. Where is the code for that? Also, is it throwing the exception on the second line? Oh, and if  you hard-code it, as you mentioned, does it work?

Comment: got it working.  Had to make it ...mdb(str(projectName)) then it started to work.  Now I'm battling with too few items error.  Damn learning curves.